# how to deploy as a web app the html static website generated by pytest in devops?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-webapps

I'm building my pipelines in the Microsoft dev Ops forge. I would like to make the test pipeline to export the generated html coverage folder and deploy it as webb app. To allow developer to monitor which files need maintainer love.

Here is my test.yaml file:

```yaml
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - main

pool:
  vmImage: windows-latest

steps:
  - task: UsePythonVersion@0
    inputs:
      versionSpec: "3.10"
    displayName: "Use Python 3.10"
  - script: python -m pip install toto pytest pytest-cov pytest-deadfixtures
    displayName: "Install dependencies"
  - script: pytest --color=yes --cov --cov-report=html
    displayName: "Test with pytest"
  - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
    displayName: "Publish coverage"
    inputs:
      pathToPublish: "./htmlcov/"
      artifactName: "coverage"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Prepare the static webApp

The first step to deploy your static resource is to create the web application where the files will be deployed.

To create a static web App, first go to the Azure portal: https://portal.azure.com/
There click on **create new resource** and select **Static Web Apps** and then Select **Create**.

> you will may need to request free trial of Azure services if you don't have any subscription. Don't be alamarmed the static web app is free for open-source/recreational application.

Create a new static web app with the values specific to your Azure subscription and your preferred parameter arguments.

> you can use an existing Resource Group or create a new one.

In **deployment details** click on "other" and finally select **create + review**. The SWA deployment will start. Copy the deployment token and paste the deployment token value into a text editor for use on another screen. Click the Close button.

More detailed information and some screenshots can be found in [this article](https://juarezjunior.medium.com/how-to-publish-azure-static-web-apps-with-azure-devops-4d21146e879e) be aware that some buttons have changed since its publication.

### Create the Pipeline Task in Azure DevOps

In the pipeline we don't need to use artifacts as the htmlcov folder is generated by the test. So after generation:

```yaml
- script: pytest --color=yes --cov --cov-report=html
    displayName: "Test with pytest"
```

Add an extra step shipping the generated folder to the application:

```yaml
- task: AzureStaticWebApp@0
    inputs:
      app_location: "/htmlcov"
      azure_static_web_apps_api_token: $(DEPLOYMENT_TOKEN)
```

Add the `DEPLOYMENT_TOKEN` to the variable list of the pipeline.

> Don't foget to tick the hidden variable box

Run the pipeline and the files will be automatically shiped to the application.