# how to deploy an html documentation page in devOps?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-webapps

My devOps pipeline is building the documentation of my python lib. This documentation is built with Sphinx so I export the whole docs/_build folder as an artifact but I don't know how to deploy it as a documentation website.

Here is my doc.yaml:

```yaml
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - main

pool:
  vmImage: windows-latest

steps:
  - task: UsePythonVersion@0
    inputs:
      versionSpec: "3.10"
    displayName: "Use Python 3.10"

  - script: python -m pip install nox
    displayName: "Install dependencies"

  - script: nox -s docs
    displayName: "Build static docs"

  - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
    displayName: "Publish HTML"
    inputs:
      pathToPublish: "./docs/_build/html/"
      artifactName: "documentation"
```

Note that the build is a static website.

Comment: What have you tried? What hasn't worked? What resources have you consulted?

Comment: There is a misandurstanding here. These question are not easily answered on SO (or they require a more accurate wording that I don't yet have). If someone already know that's for the better. If not I'll share my findings so that the next beginner will find it as I always do like here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/377222/creating-automated-tests-using-google-earth-engine-python-api. Please don't close my questions, I'll populate the answers if nobody shows up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Prepare the static webApp

The first step to deploy your static resource is to create the web application where the files will be deployed.

To create a static web App, first go to the Azure portal: https://portal.azure.com/

Please follow the instruction from this [medium article](https://juarezjunior.medium.com/how-to-publish-azure-static-web-apps-with-azure-devops-4d21146e879e) as the process is not automated at all an require to click on multiple buttons. You can also refer to this answer]([how to deploy as a web app the html static website generated by pytest in devops?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76631775/how-to-deploy-as-a-web-app-the-html-static-website-generated-by-pytest-in-devops/76632987#76632987)) were instruction have been written down.

Once your static app is ready, save the token.

### Create the documentation

No need to create an artifcat as you use the same pipeline to build and publish. Simply run your favorit sphinx build command:

```yaml
- script: make html # it can be wrapped in nox or directly use stb
  displayName: "Build static docs"
```

If you respected the convention from Sphinx-quickstart, the documentation should be located in `docs/_build/html`. Create a extra step to send this folder to the application:

```yaml
- task: AzureStaticWebApp@0
    inputs:
      app_location: "/docs/_build/html"
      azure_static_web_apps_api_token: $(DEPLOYMENT_TOKEN)
```

Don't forget to add the DEPLOYMENT_TOKEN that we saved earlier in the pipeline variable. Run the pipeline and the documentation will be available in the Azure app.